# How to transfer file from one machine to another machine

Tags: shell

I want to send files from one machine to another machine using SFTP and need to automate this (bash).

Example: Need to send files from my IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to another IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XYY.

How to do this?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, @Radhi. Please read the [introduction tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to provide good example guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp:

```
scp ~/my.log remote_user@remote_host.com:~/remote_path
```

Comment: Can u suggest using sftp for the same?